# Getting the path of a ClickOnce File Association

Tags: .net, wpf, shell, clickonce

I've using ClickOnce and I'm struggling with file associations. I can set up the association. Double-clicking an associated file even launches the application.

...However...

I don't know how to get access to ***the path of the file clicked*** to launch the App.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official .NET way (w/o Registry) is to look at

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData

after startup. It is a string[]